# How to release NSThread object thoroughly？

Tags: objective-c, release, nsthread

Like this title, I want know how to release NSThread object thoroughly.

This is my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  NSThread * thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithBlock:^{
    @autoreleasepool {
      sleep(3);
      NSLog(@"ended");
    }
  }];
  thread.name = @"asdf";
  [thread start];
}
```

thread will be released after execution. But "Instruments" tells me that thread still has 512kb of space in memory, and that the method is [thread start].

[Instruments output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcUX0.png)

Can I release this space, and if so, how?

Comment: Is there really an issue? It’s in the VM stack.

Comment: In fact, I don't really understand what VM stack means, so does it need to be freed?

Comment: But it does take up 524kb of my space, and if I were to create threads thousands of times, the memory footprint would soar. 

and If the thread has completed its task, it should be cleaned up completely and no longer take up my space.

Comment: You don’t know that. Create thousands and see.

Comment: I tried adding an endpoint before the for statement and read that the memory footprint was 13.9M.

And let it continue until finally, the memory footprint is 28M.

Instruments also show one thousands memory footprint types such as VM stacks......